# Cython and gcc: can't run compiled program

Tags: python, c, gcc, mingw, cython

I have a problem with python to C code translation and further compilation.

First, I installed MinGW, wrote `setup.py? script and translated python code (simplest helloworld) to C with Cython:

> `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

Then I tried to compile generated .c file:

> `gcc.exe helloworld.c -mdll -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90`

No error occurred during compilation, but when I tried to launch generated *a.exe* file, I got the following error:

> a.exe is not a valid Win32 application

I have no idea how to fix this problem.
I'm running 32-bit Vista.
 
P.S. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Cython wiki on [Embedding Cython](http://wiki.cython.org/EmbeddingCython) for creating standalone executable with Cython

Comment: I tried `cython.py --embed helloworld.py`, got larger .c file (1657 lines of code versus 1473 earlier), then tried gcc as was written in my post, but I still get this error.

Comment: It finally worked! `gcc.exe helloworld.c  -IC:\Python27\include -LC:\Python27\libs`

Answer (score 2):

The compiled file isn't an executable, it's a library (`dll`).

python modules on windows usually have a `.pyd` extension, so either rename your file to `helloworld.pyd` or use `-o helloworld.pyd` as argument for the compiler.

then you should be able to `import helloworld` from python.